# 'assembleDebug' Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

When I start a flutter app in android studio I get this error.
Can someone please help me?
I am an amateur programmer and I got this error. I have windows 10

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\USUARIO\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
         > Cannot parse result path string:        
   > Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\USUARIO\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
         > Cannot parse result path string:        
   > Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\USUARIO\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
         > Cannot parse result path string:        
   > Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\USUARIO\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
         > Cannot parse result path string:        
   > Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\USUARIO\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
         > Cannot parse result path string:        

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run an app from someone else there must be a problem with the grade version in the project, go to android=>build.gradle and check version e.g. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
If you are new to Flutter better start with an empty project:
flutter create yourAppName